# How to multiplex named pipe / fifo

Tags: named-pipes, multiplexing

Say we have a named pipe:

```
mkfifo my_named_pipe
```

say there are multiple writers writing to this named pipe:

```
node x.js > ${my_named_pipe} &
node y.js > ${my_named_pipe} &
node z.js > ${my_named_pipe} &
```

something like that - is there a reliable way to multiplex it, so that one whole message gets through each time, or can a named pipe reliable read from only one writer?

It leads me to wonder how we multiplex ports/sockets etc, I don't know how it's done.

Comment: looks like we can't multiplex named pipes....https://gist.github.com/thinkerbot/6406361

Comment: I guess I don't understand how sockets can be multiplexed but named pipes can't

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit of a naïve answer, but this works for me.

If you have multiple writers to a single FIFO and you don't want their output to be mangled then you can use `stdbuf` but only if the output is line-based. Whole paragraphs will still be interleaved.

```
stdbuf -oL node x.js > ${my_named_pipe} &
stdbuf -oL node y.js > ${my_named_pipe} &
stdbuf -oL node z.js > ${my_named_pipe} &
```

> **`man stdbuf`:** `stdbuf` - Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its standard streams.

This will only work when your original program does not adjusts its buffering of the standard output stream.